# Remote Access to Linode

Tags: linode

Hi I am a cloud Hosting in Linode with 2 different images

using the Remote Access ssh root@149.152.231.117 
I always connect to the first image (My Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Profile).
Would be possible to connect to another images ?

Comment: Different images will mean running on a different vm and so a different IP address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only boot into one disk at a time. Whichever disk your configuration profile is pointing to, looks like Ubuntu 14.04 in this case, is what you are booting.

You would need to reboot into another disk to run their distro. To have multiple VMs running at the same time would require multiple Linodes.

The exception here is if you choose to boot Ubuntu and then create a Docker container with a different distro. Then you can log into both.